# Some inequalities similar to Lagarias inequality

Tags: proof-verification, inequality, riemann-hypothesis

I have found [some inequalities](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u6uOyA-e3xnUUVbxqn4h1gbzWsGQ8VcF/view?usp=sharing) which seem to be equivalent to Lagarias inequality. It would be very nice if someone takes the time to proofread this in detail and give constructive feedback.
Thanks for your help.